Why this c code below works fine? (C Basic, Buffer overflow test)
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    arr[6] = 7; // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    
    printf("arr[6] = %d\n", arr[6]);

    return 0;
}


As I recall, it used to give a warning message when compiling and an unknown value when running.
(Or I could see a Segment Fault message).
So I would like to know from which version the code above started working correctly.
My current GCC version is as follows:
gcc-13 (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


Undefined behavior is undefined. Segfault is not guaranteed, and neither is printing any "unknown value".

Sidenote: The comment in your code is wrong. arr[6] = 7; // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  - you are assigning 7 to the seventh element so [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, indeterminate, 7] would be more appropriate (if the code had defined behavior)

This question is similar to: How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A test: Replace the arr definition to int x=1, arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, y=2;. Add printf("x=%d, y=%d\n",x,y); at the bottom. If run the program, I get x=1, y=7. So you know, where the arr[6] is stored.

@Wiimm - On the compiler I use, the value isn't stored anywhere. It just optimizes out the array and does printf("arr[6] = %d\n", 7);.

Thanks all replied!
I realize my question was inaccurate, and the good answers more than made up for my lack of clarity!

Your use of "working correctly" is wrong. For something to be working correctly, there would have to be a definition of what the correct behavior is - but there is none and the code has undefined behavior in all versions.
That means that the program could crash, print "hello world", stall or do pretty much anything, including printing arr[6] = 7, which is no more correct than any other behavior.


As I recall, it used to give a warning message when compiling and an unknown value when running. (Or I could see a Segment Fault message).
So I would like to know from which version the code above started working correctly.

Testing with every version of GCC available for x86-64 at Compiler Explorer shows none of them produces a diagnostic message for this out-of-bounds array access. Therefore, it is unlikely your recollection is correct.
Possibilities include:

There is some combination of options that does produce the message. (I tested with optimization on, which includes analysis that sometimes enables diagnostics that are not discovered without it.)
Your memory is from more than a decade ago, before GCC 4.7.3.
Some intermediate version of GCC not preserved in Compiler Explorer or for another target produced this message.
It was another compiler, such as Clang, which does produce a diagnostic.


Not crashing just means that whatever memory you overwrote with your out-of-bounds write access didn't immediateley cause code execution to crash, by e.g. overwriting return address.
Still, your program has overwritten some memory it wasn't supposed to do within its allocated variables. And in other instances, that could have been a local variable on the stack that might change the code flow later.
Memory corruption can lead to many things, not just "immediate segfault", and it not crashing immediately is not "the program works fine :) :)"
Take e.g. the program
#include <stdio.h>

void bad_func(int index) {
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    arr[index] = 7;
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", index, arr[index]);
    return;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
        bad_func(i),
        printf("..survived, phew!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

compiled with gcc -o crash crash.c. Meaning, we are slowly increasing the index at which the memory corruption happens. On my Ubuntu machine with gcc 12.3.0 I get:
$ ./crash
arr[0] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[1] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[2] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[3] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[4] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[5] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[6] = 7
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

On Windows with GCC 14.1.0 I get
>crash.exe
arr[0] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[1] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[2] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[3] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[4] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[5] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[6] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[7] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[8] = 7
..survived, phew
<crash>

So, depending on the compiler and explicit memory layout, a SEGFAULT happens at certain indices.
As said before, a SEGFAULT crash is just one of the possible consequences of the out of memory write your program does though. Consider the program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void bad_func(int index) {
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int my_variable = 0;
    arr[index] = 7;
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", index, arr[index]);
    if (my_variable) {
      printf("my_variable suddenly changed!! %d\n", my_variable);
    }
    return;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
        bad_func(i),
        printf("..survived, phew!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

when compiled on my linux system with gcc -O0 -o crash -fno-stack-protector crash.c I get
arr[0] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[1] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[2] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[3] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[4] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[5] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[6] = 7
..survived, phew!
arr[7] = 7
my_variable suddenly changed!! 7
..survived, phew!
arr[8] = 7
..survived, phew!
Memory access error (core dumped)

In this particular case of memory layout, the access arr[7] was actually equivalent to overwriting the int my_variable variable. And this had effects on the further program flow.
